# Unable to subscribe messages on device from Azure IOT hub using MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

`This is the code i am using to publish messages.

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "C:\\Users\\prana\\Desktop\\Azure Python\\BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem"
device_id = "edgedevice1"
sas_token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=PASSDEMO1.azure-     devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fedgedevice1&sig=fUHFW%2BH0eEOJFqppkQWQS8Mm8I8XvvobhqH1KUuXyyg%3D&se=1686206027"
iot_hub_name = "PASSDEMO1"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Device sent message")


client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311,clean_session=0)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish

client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" +
                   device_id + "/?api-version=2021-04-12", password=sas_token)

client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=None, keyfile=None,
           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)

client.publish("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/", '{"id":123}', qos=1,retain = True)
client.loop_forever()
```

This is the code i am using to subscribe messages.

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "C:\\Users\\prana\\Desktop\\Azure Python\\BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem"
device_id = "edgedevice2"
sas_token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=PASSDEMO1.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fedgedevice2&sig=HdHM2STMT8eB6JJjQFSJKjy2FFvoNhFI%2Fqj%2Fb0c1TcY%3D&se=1686206053"
iot_hub_name = "PASSDEMO1"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/devicebound/#", qos=1)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Received message: " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))


client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, clean_session=1)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" +
                       device_id + "/?api-version=2021-04-12", password=sas_token)

client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=None, keyfile=None,
               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)

client.loop_forever()
```

I am able to send messages to the azure iot hub successfully by publishing to a topic using edgedevice1 .However when i subscribe to the topic using edgedevice2 i  am unable to recieve messages. The on_message function in the second program does not get executed. How do i resolve this ?

Comment: Make sure to send the message
```  az iot device c2d-message send -d devicename -n IotHubName --data 'Hello World' --props 'key0=value0;key1=value1' ``` 

before executing receiving a message CODE . ```az iot device c2d-message send --device-id <device_id> --hub-name <hub_name> --data "<message>"```

Comment: @Sampath Hey thanks for replying. Are we supposed to type the above code in azure CLI ? Can you please clarify ?

Comment: as we have device-to-cloud and cloud-to-device message. we are will send a message to the device using CLi or a message to [device](https://i.imgur.com/LAREqOr.png) and receive a [message](https://i.imgur.com/nedH7QZ.png)

Comment: ```az iot device c2d-message send -d yourdeviceid -n yourIothubname --data 'Hello World' --props 'key0=value0;key1=value1'```

Comment: yes with Cli. use az login to log in or send a message  with send message to [device](https://i.imgur.com/WDqRzrq.png) and then run your receiving message code

Comment: reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub) and [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/main/samples)

Comment: @Sampath Yes, i ran the command on azure cli and i received the message. I am able to subscribe to the messages from cli. But still when i run the publish python code and send a message, it is not getting subscribed. I am able to send c2d messages but i want it to work specifically via mqtt , by subscribing to a specific topic.

Comment: give a sample of how to connect with MQTT, send messages and receiving and git reference for your example

Comment: receiving is not working

Comment: I have given the example code in my question itself

Comment: I have you sample example how to connect with iot hub with mqqtt and gave you reference for how to connect with x509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> I have refered thisMQTT to communicate with [Azure IoT Hub with x509](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub)  and [azure-iot-sdk-python X509](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/main/samples).

[image]

**Code:**

```py
import  time
import  json
import  paho.mqtt.client  as  mqtt

mqtt_broker = f"{iot_hub_name}.azure-devices.net"
mqtt_port = 8883
mqtt_username = f"{iot_hub_name}.azure-devices.net/{device_id}/api-version=2018-06-30"

mqtt_topic = f"devices/{device_id}/messages/events/"
def  on_connect(client,  userdata,  flags,  rc):
print(f"Connected: {rc}")
client.subscribe(mqtt_topic)
def  on_message(client,  userdata,  msg):
print(f"Received: {msg.payload.decode()}")
def  send_message(client,  message):
print("Sending message:",  message)
client.publish(mqtt_topic,  json.dumps(message))
print("Message sent successfully!")
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id,  protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
client.username_pw_set(username=mqtt_username,  password=mqtt_password)
client.tls_set()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(mqtt_broker,  mqtt_port,  keepalive=60)
client.loop_start()
message = {"message":  "Hello, Azure IoT Hub!"}
send_message(client,  message) 
time.sleep(5)
client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

- Refer this for Azure IoT hub using the [MQTT with X509](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-amqp-support.md) and [IoT hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub.md)